# Send message to channel at random using lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a list of channels and a running background thread on time.sleep. My goal is to send a random message from a list_of_msgs=[] to a random channel from a channel_list=[].

This is how I'm populating the channel list:

```
chan_list = []
        for server in self.bot.servers:
            for channel in server.channels:
                if channel.type == discord.ChannelType.text:
                    chan_list.append(channel)
        print(', '.join(map(str, chan_list))) ###for testing###
```

What would be the proper way to send_message from the list to a channel on the other list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random
random.choice(chan_list)
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: Excellent, sweet and simple. I'm newer to python so it's good to learn these things! Thanks so much, works just how I need it to!